# I'm having a problem building ios using codemagic

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, podfile, codemagic

[image]

Error running pod install in codemagic
I use android studio and I want to build ios with codemagic but he give me the Erorr "Error running pod install in codemagic" how I can build ios without error

Answer (score 0):

scroll up the command output you should be able to see actual error message like

```
    [!] Could not automatically select an Xcode workspace. Specify one in your Podfile like so:

        workspace 'path/to/Workspace.xcworkspace'
```

Comment: Failed to build iOS app
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'cloud_firestore' not found
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8

Comment: as I understand you made some changes and faced a new issue now? if so you need to search for existing answers first or create a new question